# How much faster is C than compiled elisp?

Tags: elisp, byte-compilation

I'd like to write some lightning-fast functions for analyzing LaTeX code. Because they could involve a lot of complicated processing of large documents, I don't know whether it's a good idea to write them completely in Lisp or not. How fast is byte-compiled Lisp compared to C, and how intensive does the processing have to be for the user to notice a difference?

---

Specifically, I'm trying to implement better functions for finding certain types of errors -- for example, neither show-paren-mode nor smartparens-latex are smart enough to notice that \left and \right are brackets that must match with another \left or \right. These programs also don't know that there are features brackets can't match across (so if it encounters one of these features, which will have to be defined a complicated way since it's environment-dependent), it should report a paren mismatch.

Because of the potential complexity of the code (parsing LaTeX can depend on the environment in complicated ways) and the fact that it has to be fast enough that the user won't notice a delay when, for example, they move the cursor over a parenthesis, I'm concerned about optimizing the code, and I want to know whether I can get away with writing careful Lisp or if it would be smarter to implement one or more primitives to help with the grunt-work.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to swap the contestants in the title?  I rarely see claims about languages performing better than C and when I do, the tests feature abysmal C code...

Comment: As for the answer, this is hard to answer on a theoretical basis, writing code and measuring afterwards would make for a much more useful result than discussing the yet unknown.

Comment: Thanks wasamasa - I do indeed want to swap them. While writing my code in both languages would be the best way to gauge performance, that sounds like a big time investment?

Comment: It's not like you need to do a full implementation in both, a suitable prototype representing the workload you envision shall suffice.  That being said, most of the time you won't need that level of sophistication and writing your code in elisp is fine.

Comment: I've seen benchmarking that showed that Common Lisp can be faster than C.  It might be worthwhile to find that (I'll see if I can chase it up) and rewrite the CL functions in Elisp, just to see how that compares.

Comment: Your specific example can be implemented in smartparens btw, see its HTML tag or ruby block matching support for instance.  Newer Emacs versions support the latter example in show-paren-mode as well.

Comment: I was thinking of an old post "Make Lisp 15x faster than Python or 4x faster than Java", but it's deleted.  There's an article available on [How to make Lisp go faster than C](http://www.iaeng.org/IJCS/issues_v32/issue_4/IJCS_32_4_19.pdf).  Regarding the specific issue of analysing LaTeX code, it may be worth checking in with the [LaTeXML](http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/contact.html) and [LaMaPUn](https://trac.kwarc.info/lamapun/) dev teams.  Current work there is in Perl and/or C, and in Rust; see recent [blog post](https://authorea.com/92721).

Comment: Oh, I found the blog post I mentioned with the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100130114252/http://blog.postabon.com/make-lisp-15x-faster-than-python-or-4x-faster).

Comment: Writing a good editor for structured texts is **hard**. It requires certain mastery, theoretical knowledge (in the field of formal languages and automata) and lots of practice. To be honest, I think that neither C nor ELisp are good candidates for the task. C is too verbose and too low-level. ELisp doesn't have any good optimizers, plus it's hard to constrain and formally verify it. You'd be better off doing something like that in ML / Haskell / Rust and family.

Comment: Unfortunately, Emacs text engine is based on regular expressions, which work well for what it's worth, but most structured languages today are context-free, so regex isn't a good tool for parsing those. Recent years had seen the rise of PEG parsers. Perhaps, if you could write a multi-purpose PEG parser which interfaces with Emacs, that would be a very valuable addition to the editor. There's been rumours Emacs will soon have an FFI interface, but if not, there's libffi you could use to interface your code with Emacs (a bit slower, but careful design of communication protocol could help).